# is there any plugin in QGIS that show the train/plane route

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, route

I am currently working on QGIS for a project, and I want to map the route between two stadiums. I managed to create a route for the bus using the orstools plugin, but I can't manage to create a route for the train or plane. Is there any plugin that allows me to?

Comment: I guess plane would be a straight line between the two airports...

Comment: that makes sense, but what about train?

Comment: Do the same you have done for the bus, but use only the railway!!! You can find them on OSM

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap ?